# when using Mybatis, I encounter the avaticaSqlexception. Does anyone know the reason?

Tags: mybatis

when using Mybatis, I encounter the `avaticaSqlexception`. Does anyone know the reason?

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="com.*">
  insert into stats_sms (pin,prizeId,templateId,sendTime) values ('123','123','123','123')
</inserte>
```

Comment: you need to provide more information, namely stacktrace with the full error message.

Comment: Why a parameter in the first place? You don't use any in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The value you pass are all hardcode string,so change `parameterType` to `String` or just remove `parameterType` attribute

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="String">
  insert into stats_sms (pin,prizeId,templateId,sendTime) values ('123','123','123','123')
</insert>
```

OR

```
<insert id="insert">
  insert into stats_sms (pin,prizeId,templateId,sendTime) values ('123','123','123','123')
</insert>
```